# Failed to Start Derby Database

Tags: java, apache-flex, tomcat, jdbc, derby

So I'm quite new to Java and Derby. I'm using both with my Flex app on Tomcat 7.

When I make a call to Java from Flex the login function works fine but my getUserByUsername function does not.

```
public Boolean loginUser(String username, String password) throws Exception
{
    Connection c = null;
    String hashedPassword = new String();

    try
    {
        c = ConnectionHelper.getConnection();

        PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username=?");
        ps.setString(1, username);

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next())
        {
            hashedPassword = rs.getString("password");
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

        if(Password.check(password, hashedPassword))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();throw new DAOException(e);
    }
    finally
    {
        ConnectionHelper.closeConnection(c);
    }
}

public User getUserByUsername(String username) throws DAOException
{
    //System.out.println("Executing DAO.getUserByName:" + username);

    User user = new User();

    Connection c = null;
    try
    {

        c = ConnectionHelper.getConnection();

        PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?");
        ps.setString(1, username);

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next())
        {
            user.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            user.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
            user.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
            user.setTeam(rs.getString("team"));
            user.setScore(rs.getInt("score"));
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new DAOException(e);
    }
    finally
    {
        ConnectionHelper.closeConnection(c);
    }
    return user;
}
```

The stack I get in Flex is useless as far as I can tell:

> Flex Message (flex.messaging.messages.ErrorMessage)     clientId = 8EB6D37B-7E0B-01B0->AA55-457722B9036C    correlationId = A39E574F-CFC6-51FE-6CBE-451AF329E2F8    destination >= service    messageId = 8EB6DF4C-650B-BDD7-7802-B813A61C8DC8    timestamp = >1401318734645    timeToLive = 0    body = null    code =  Server.Processing    message =  >services.DAOException : java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database >'/Applications/blazeds/tomcat/webapps/testdrive/WEB-INF/database/game_db', see the next >exception for details.    details =  null    rootCause =  ASObject(23393258)>>{message=java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database >'/Applications/blazeds/tomcat/webapps/testdrive/WEB-INF/database/game_db', see the next >exception for details., suppressed=[], localizedMessage=java.sql.SQLException: Failed to >start database '/Applications/blazeds/tomcat/webapps/testdrive/WEB->INF/database/game_db', see the next exception for details., cause=java.sql.SQLException}    >body =  null    extendedData =  null

My first thought was that it was just an error in my function (maybe someone else will notice it) but I've been looking through it for a couple hours and I can't see anything.

After that I thought maybe Derby had a problem with concurrent connections. I saw somewhere that Embedded JDBC can only handle one connection so I changed the driver from Embedded to Client which once again resulted in the login function working and the other an error saying the url in the connection was null. Any thoughts? Thanks ahead of time for any ideas.

EDIT:

```
package services;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;

public class ConnectionHelper
{

private String url;

private static ConnectionHelper instance;

public String getUrl()
{
    return url;
}

private ConnectionHelper()
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
        String str = URLDecoder.decode(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("services").toString(),"UTF-8");
        str= str.substring(0, str.indexOf("classes/services")); 
        if ( str.startsWith("file:/C:",0)){
            str=str.substring(6);
        }
        else{
            str=str.substring(5);
        }
        url = "jdbc:derby:" + str + "database/game_db";
        System.out.println("Database url "+url);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static ConnectionHelper getInstance()
{
    if (instance == null)
        instance = new ConnectionHelper();
    return instance;
}

public static Connection getConnection() throws java.sql.SQLException
{
    return DriverManager.getConnection(getInstance().getUrl());
}

public static void closeConnection(Connection c)
{
    try
    {
        if (c != null)
        {
            c.close();
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: show us your `ConnectionHelper` class.

Comment: When you get the "see next Exception for details", here's what to do: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain

Comment: Thanks Bryan. Turns out I was getting a version error hidden in there. Doesn't explain why one function worked and not the other but it works nonetheless. Peace.

Comment: @Bryan If you happen to see this I have one other question. With my above setup, can you see anything that will prevent lots of simultaneous connections to my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is NO problem with multiple connections in embedded mode. Full stop.

That said, what you may have come across, is that only one **jvm process** can access the **Derby database files** at a time. But that jvm may well have 1000s of threads each with their own connection to Derby (resources permitting, of course).